# Crear efecto hover de resaltado bajo el texto de un elemento de menú

Tags: html, css

[image: El efecto hover como el de youtube.]

El efecto hover como el de youtube.

Comment: Aqui lo tienes: [demo](http://jsbin.com/loneluv/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: border-bottom 80ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected,
li:hover {
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Trending</li>
  <li>Subscriptions</li>
</ul>
```

La explicación de este fenómeno se encuentra en dos secciones del código previamente señalado. En la primera parte de los estilos, aparece la línea `transition: border-bottom 80ms`. Esta línea indica que cada vez que se cambie la propiedad descrita en el elemento, va a realizarse con una transición de 80 milisegundos. En la segunda parte, se define el estilo que va a tener el `li` cuando se le posicione el cursor encima (:hover). Al modificar la propiedad `border-bottom`, se pone en práctica la regla de transición definida antes, por lo que se crea el efecto. Existe una forma de aplicarle dicha transición a todas las propiedades de un elemento y es escribiendo simplemente `transition: all __ms;`. Véase que también se pueden usar distintos tipos de notaciones de tiempo, como s para los segundos etc...

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quizás se podría beneficiar con un pequeño comentario explicando brevemente cómo es que se está logrando el estilo y la transición. Está el código que funciona, pero ¿cómo y por qué?

Comment: @Mariano: Ok Gracias por el comentario. Voy a editar la respuesta.